# Custom icon for <a-cursor>

Tags: aframe

i have `<a-scene>` with a `<a-cursor>` which has the default look for display. Can I change the look and feel to a **pointer** or *icon* of some sort?

Answer (score 4):

just put anything inside the `<a-cursor>` 
check out the live [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13tvou9f/1/), and for sure check out the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/), they're full of examples, including [creating a ring - shaped cursor](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/cursor.html#example).

**UPDATE**
For some reason this anwser is getting attention, so i'd like to elaborate.

You can either use `<a-cursor>` primitive:

```
<a-camera>
  <a-cursor>
    <a-entity id="myCursor"></a-entity>
  </a-cursor>
</a-camera>
```

like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dchg3jc1/), or utilize the `cursor` component:

```
<a-camera>
    <a-entity id="myCursor" cursor></a-entity>
</a-camera>
```

like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dchg3jc1/4/).

---

Nonetheless do not be afraid of the [official docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/), the [algolia](https://www.algolia.com/ref/docsearch?utm_source=docsearch&utm_medium=link&utm_term=footer&utm_campaign=aframe.io) search makes it really easy to look through.